# Reconnecting serveral peerConnections after page reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I'm creating a web application for monitoring by smartphones using WebRTC, and for the signalling server I'm using socket.io.

When I'm sending a stream, I create an *RTCPeerConnection* object on the "watch" page that receives this stream. Streams I send on separate pages. The user can attach up to four streams from a smartphone, so on the "watch" page there are up to four *RTCPeerConnection* objects.

Streams are received automatically as soon as the offer from the "transmit" page appears, then the *RTCPeerConnection* object is created on the "watch" page and connected to the standard WebRTC schema.

"transmit" page:

```
  function onCreateOfferSuccess(sdp){
  //console.log(sdp);
  pc.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));
  console.log('ask');
  socket.emit('ask', {"sdp":JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription),
                      "user": loggedUserID,
                      "fromSocket": ownSocket});
}
```

"watch" page:

```
socket.on('ask', function(offer){
   if (offer.user === loggedUserID){
      TempDescriptions = JSON.parse(offer.sdp);
      console.log(TempDescriptions)
      currTransmiterSocket = offer.fromSocket;
      console.log(currTransmiterSocket);
      getStream();
}

function getStream(){
   try {
       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log(time, 'getStream()');
           connection = getPeerConnection();

           connection.setRemoteDescription(
           new RTCSessionDescription(TempDescriptions),
           function() {
               connection.createAnswer(gotDescription, function(error){
           console.log(error)
           });
           }, function(error){
               console.log(error)
           });
       }, getStreamDelay*3000)
       getStreamDelay++
   }

   catch(err){
       console.log(err);
   }
};
```

My web application requires functionality in which when we exit from the "watch" page and return to it again, all previously included streams must be displayed.

To implement this functionality, I use the *oniceconnectionstatechange* method. If the stream is disconnected, the *iceRestart* function is executed which creates the offer with the option *{iceRestart: true}*

"transmit" page:

```
var options_with_restart = {offerToReceiveAudio: false,
                            offerToReceiveVideo: true,
                            iceRestart: true};

function iceRestart(event){  
  try{
      setTimeout(function(){
       pc.createOffer(options_with_restart).then(onCreateOfferSuccess, onCreateOfferError);
      },1000);
  } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
```

The problem is that when I restart the "watch" page, all pages "transmit" send to ask at once. Only one object is connected, although four *RTCPeerConnection* objects are created at once (let's assume that the user sends four streams).

I have been struggling with this problem for several days. I tried to set an increasing time delay on subsequent calls to the *getStream()* function as seen in the above code, I tried to check the `signallingState` connections before executing the *getStream()* function, I tried several other methods but none of them worked.

If you need some part of my code to help, please write.

edit:

gotDescription() method in "watch" page.

```
function gotDescription(sdp) {
   try{
       connection.setLocalDescription(sdp,
       function() {
       registerIceCandidate();
       socket.emit('response', {"sdp": sdp,
                                "user": loggedUserID,
                                "fromSocket": ownSocket,
                                "toSocket": currTransmiterSocket});
        }, function(error){
               console.log(error)
           });
   } catch(err){
       console.log(err);
   }
}
```

I add `console.log` with `RTCPeerConnection object`

console output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQXkE.png[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQXkE.png)

log shows that the `signalingState` of connection is "stable" but when I develop the object, `signalingState` is equal to "have-remote-offer"

[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Pl8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `TempDescriptions` global variable, and pass the sdp to `getStream(offer.sdp)` directly.

Otherwise, you've `socket.on('ask', function(offer){` called 4 times, overwriting `TempDescriptions`. Then 3+ seconds later your 4 `setTimeout`s roll around, all accessing the final value of `TempDescriptions` only.

That's probably why only one RTCPeerConnection re-connects.

In general, using time delay to separate connections seems like a bad idea, as it slows down re-connection. Instead, why not send an `id`? E.g.

```
socket.emit('ask', {id: connectionNumber++,
                    sdp: JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription),
                    user: loggedUserID,
                    fromSocket: ownSocket});
```

#### Update: Stop adding global variables to `window`

Whenever you assign to an undeclared variable like this:

```
connection = getPeerConnection();
```

...it creates a global on `window`, e.g. `window.connection`, and you have the same problem. You have 4 connection, but you're storing them in one variable.

Type `"use strict";` at the head of your source file to catch this:

```
ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable connection
```

#### Scoping: The general problem

You're dealing with 4 connections here, but you lack an approach for scoping each instance.

Most other languages would tell you to create a class and make object instances, and put everything including `connection` on `this`. That's one good approach. In JS you can use closures instead. But at minimum you still need 4 variables holding the 4 connections, or an array of `connections`. Then you look up—e.g. from the `id` I mentioned—which connection to deal with.

Also, your `try`/`catch`es aren't going to catch asynchronous errors. Instead of defining all these callbacks, I strongly recommend [using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), or even [async/await](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions) when dealing with the highly asynchronous WebRTC API. This makes scoping trivial. E.g.

```
const connections = [];

socket.on('ask', async ({user, id, sdp, fromSocket}) => {
  try {
    if (user != loggedUserID) return;
    if (!connections[id]) {
      connections[id] = getPeerConnection();
      registerIceCandidate(connections[id]);
    }
    const connection = connections[id];
    await connection.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(sdp));
    await connection.setLocalDescription(await connection.createAnswer());
    socket.emit('response', {sdp,
                             user: loggedUserID,
                             fromSocket: ownSocket,
                             toSocket: fromSocket});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

This way the error handling is solid.

Comment: thanks for help. as you suggested i delete `TempDescriptions` variable and pass sdp to `getStream()`. Expected result is different, now when I attach four streams and refresh the page I get only one stream and three errors: `DOMException: Failed to set local answer sdp: Called in wrong state: kStable` which is generated in gotDescription() function ( i update question with gotDescription() method). I searched for information about this error earlier because it also appeared, but Google does not know much about it.

Comment: I've found that `getDescription()` gets the same `sdp` on each call instead of receiving sdp of every connection, that is why i'm getting `kstable` state but I do not know how to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for answer and your time. I understood what you wrote but I have a problem with one thing, as you wrote earlier when 'ask' is emitting I should also attach connectionNumber ++, the problem is that 'transmit' page has no acces to the other 'transmit' pages so connectionNumber will always be the same.

Comment: @SalimAzeri It is up to you to decide how to differentiate the various "transmit" pages. You could make up a random id, for example. Since you want to re-connect with them that's probably a good idea, so they'll appear in the same order as last time. If that's not important, then forget the `id` and just assign them a `connection` as they come in.

Comment: I created function for generating random id, one more thing, i copied function from socket.on('ask') and i get error that sdp is not defined, how should i catch sdp from setLocalDescription ?

Comment: @SalimAzeri Ah `offer` is an object, whose contents may change over time. Just copy the fields you need into temporaries, like you had, except into local `const` variables, or use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the same effect. I've updated the example to use destructuring.